# Corda in docker

Tags: docker-compose, corda, activemq-artemis

When running corda node in docker i get an ActiveMQ error:

```
Pulling node ... done
Recreating node_1 ... done
Attaching to node_1
node_1  |
node_1  |    ______               __
node_1  |   / ____/     _________/ /___ _
node_1  |  / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         There are two rules for financial success:
node_1  | / /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          1) Don't tell everything you know.
node_1  | \____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/
node_1  |
node_1  | --- Corda Open Source 3.3-corda (c834162) -----------------------------------------------
node_1  |
node_1  |
node_1  | Logs can be found in                    : /opt/corda/logs
node_1  | Database connection url is              : jdbc:h2:tcp://172.23.0.2:35117/node
node_1  | Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : 0.0.0.0:10002
node_1  | RPC connection address                  : 0.0.0.0:10003
node_1  | RPC admin connection address            : 0.0.0.0:10004
node_1  | [ERROR] 10:35:37+0000 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup
node_1  |  org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
node_1  |       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
node_1  |       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.ArtemisMessagingClient.start(ArtemisMessagingClient.kt:39) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCMessagingClient.start(RPCMessagingClient.kt:19) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.Node.startMessagingService(Node.kt:308) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:256) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:700) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:152) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:138) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:124) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:131) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:699) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:347) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:207) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:361) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:203) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:126) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1  |       at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
node_1 exited with code 1
```

The node runs fine on local machine outside of docker.
Can anyone give me some info about why this error occurs ?

One repository contains corda node files and this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

RUN mkdir -p /opt/corda/
COPY corda.jar /opt/corda/
COPY corda-webserver.jar /opt/corda/

RUN chmod +x /opt/corda/*.jar

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 10002
EXPOSE 10003
EXPOSE 10004

WORKDIR /opt/corda/

CMD ["java", "-Xmx512m", "-jar", "corda.jar"]
```

Other repository contains node specific config files and a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  node:
    image: private/repository/with/above/docker:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "10002:10002"
      - "10003:10003"
      - "10004:10004"
    volumes:
      - ./config/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
      - ./config/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
      - ./logs/:/opt/corda/logs/
      - ~/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/
```

Exert from node.conf

```
"p2pAddress" : "0.0.0.0:10002",
"rpcSettings" : {
    "address" : "0.0.0.0:10003",
    "adminAddress" : "0.0.0.0:10004"
},
```

The nodes are up and running without docker, but we really would prefer to run them within a docker container.

Comment: Can you post your DockerFile

Comment: Change your RPC admin connection address to 127.0.0.1:10004 and try again?

Comment: I have added my docker files

Comment: Also, ive tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error when trying to dockerize my corda nodes (v3.3).
After trying the different permutations it seemed the one responsible for the error was the adminAddress. Try setting the host for the RPC admin connection to 'localhost', that did it for me.

```
"p2pAddress" : "PartyA:10002",
"rpcSettings" : {
    "address" : "0.0.0.0:10003",
    "adminAddress": "localhost:10004"
},
```

'PartyA' being the container_name in my docker-compose file.